# Request fails to load an image using Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

Link to answer in Github : https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/2155

I try to load an image from a Url :

```
/**
 * Binding adapter used to display images from URL using Picasso
 */
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun bindImage(layout: FrameLayout, url: String?) {

    val imageView: ImageView = layout.findViewById(R.id.image)
    val builder = Picasso.Builder(imageView.context)
    builder.listener { _, _, exception -> exception.printStackTrace() }
    builder.build().load("https://via.placeholder.com/600/568c72").into(imageView)
}
```

It gives me following error message :

```
com.squareup.picasso.Downloader$ResponseException: 410 Gone
2020-02-23 19:14:08.112 2764-2764/com.sample.android.storytel W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.UrlConnectionDownloader.load(UrlConnectionDownloader.java:96)
2020-02-23 19:14:08.112 2764-2764/com.sample.android.storytel W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.NetworkRequestHandler.load(NetworkRequestHandler.java:47)
2020-02-23 19:14:08.112 2764-2764/com.sample.android.storytel W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:206)
2020-02-23 19:14:08.112 2764-2764/com.sample.android.storytel W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
2020-02-23 19:14:08.113 2764-2764/com.sample.android.storytel W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
2020-02-23 19:14:08.113 2764-2764/com.sample.android.storytel W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2020-02-23 19:14:08.113 2764-2764/com.sample.android.storytel W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2020-02-23 19:14:08.113 2764-2764/com.sample.android.storytel W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2020-02-23 19:14:08.113 2764-2764/com.sample.android.storytel W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2020-02-23 19:14:08.113 2764-2764/com.sample.android.storytel W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:411)
```

But when I load image from a browser like Google chrome, it shows image as expected : https://via.placeholder.com/600/568c72

Why my request fails using Picasso?

Comment: Have you tried other images? Perhaps it's that particular image service giving your troubles. The `410` HTTP Error Code usually means the object your are trying to retrieve used to be there, but now is not.

Comment: I ran `https://via.placeholder.com/600/568c72` on postman,
seems to return the image back okay. green, 600x600

Comment: can you try appending .png to your endpoint, as seen on [link](https://placeholder.com/)

Comment: @CoryRoy, Yes I tried other images, but I received same error.

Comment: @EvOlaNdLuPiZ, I added .png at the end of url but I received same problem.

Comment: yep. somethings up with this. my best guess it's on the server side on how they're sending their resources back to the caller. the fact i can call it from postman shows me that it works or use to work, not sure if postman is reading a cache. the fact that i ran it on my avd and it's throwing 403/401, means a lot. also i saw you had already opened an issue on this in github, might be useful to link it so others see what jake said. :)